# Setting word document table cell margin programmatically using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

As we can change default table cells margin in MS WORD using this steps

```
Click the table.
On the Table menu, click Table Properties, and then click the Table tab.
Click Options.
Under Default cell margins, enter the new values you want.
```

and exactly I want to ask how to do this programmatically I have tried `top and bottom padding` properties but it did not work and also I tried `spacing` but I did not work too so is there any way to set default cell margin using `Microsoft.Interop.Word` libraries thank you so much

PS:
I am adding tables in header and footer using `Microsoft.Interop.Word`everything gone perfect expect this :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is Table padding, and there is also Cell padding.  I'm guessing that Table padding contains the default values to apply to new cells added to the table.  Probably use Cell padding to change the existing cells.  E.g.

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    Documents docs = app.Documents;
    Document doc = docs.Open("C:\\temp\\Test2.docx", ReadOnly:true);
    Table t = doc.Tables[1];
    double b1 = t.BottomPadding;
    double t1 = t.TopPadding;
    double r1 = t.RightPadding;
    double l1 = t.LeftPadding;

    Range r = t.Range;
    Cells cells = r.Cells;
    for (int i = 1; i <= cells.Count; i++) {
        Cell cell = cells[i];
        double b2 = cell.BottomPadding;
        double t2 = cell.TopPadding;
        double r2 = cell.RightPadding;
        double l2 = cell.LeftPadding;

        // e.g. Here is the edit:
        cell.TopPadding = 21.6f;
        cell.BottomPadding = 28.8f;

        Range r2b = cell.Range;
        String txt = r2b.Text;
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cell);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(r2b);
    }

    doc.Close(false);
    app.Quit(false);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cells);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(r);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(t);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(docs);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
```